# How to filter search input for two categories?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs3

Following filter function computes the input of a `search input field` to only display elements, with a similar `title` like the `search input`:

```
const filteredNews = computed(() => {
    if (state.filter) {
        return props.news.filter(item => {
            return state.filter.toLowerCase().split(" ").every(v => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v))
        });
    } else {
        return props.news;
    }
})
```

`search input field`:

```
<input class="filter-input" type="search" placeholder="Suche" v-model="state.filter">
```

the elements are then displayed in a `v-for` loop:

```
<div class="news-gallery" v-for="(card, key) in filteredNews" :key=key>
    // items...
</div>
```

Now I want to filter not only for `title` but also `location`. How would I need to change the `filter function` to achieve that?

Something like:

```
const filteredNews = computed(() => {
    if (state.filter) {
        return props.news.filter(item => {
            return state.filter.toLowerCase().split(" ").every(v => {
                item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v),
                item.location.toLowerCase().includes(v)
            })
        });
    } else {
        return props.news;
    }
})
```

Comment: Looks like your search input is generic. So instead of search for particular field in the `item` object, you can search for any like this : `Object.values(item).includes(v)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple way. Just change:

```
item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v)
```

to:

```
item.title.toLowerCase().includes(v) || item.location.toLowerCase().includes(v))
```